# freetds.log file is HUGE in pymssql. How to disable?

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I am using pymssql in Ubuntu 15.10 connect to a SQL Server 2014 database in Windows Server 2012. When using pymssql, a freetds.log file in created in ~/Work/tsql/freetds.log. I have no idea how that was specified. Note that I am running my script from ~/Work/dir1/bin/runScript.py, so somehow that log file is getting creative at the relative path ../../tsql, or the absolute log path.

The freetds.log file grows at about 500MB/10s. I almost immediately run out of disk space. Does anyone know how to turn the logging of that file off? The dump_file is not set my freetds.conf file(s).

Answer (score 3):

I turned on TDS logging using [this](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/logging.htm) However, I did not find a formal way to turn it off. I removed log file (/tmp/freetds.log in my case) and it solved my problem.

Check your `*/freetds.conf` location, where you specify log file destination. comment out that line and test if it works.